# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error calling SOAP service from PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm attempting to access this [web service](http://www.neugroup.com/workarea/servercontrolws.asmx?op=LoadListSummary) via SOAP from PHP using this code:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$wsdl_path = "http://www.neugroup.com/workarea/servercontrolws.asmx?WSDL";

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array(
  "trace"      => 1,
  "exceptions" => 0)
);
try {
  $result = $client->LoadListSummary(array(
    'LangID' => 1033,
    'FolderPath' => 'path/',
    'MaxResults' => 500,
    'OrderKey' => 'Title',
    'Direction' => 'Ascending',
    'Preview' => 0,
    'Recursive' => 0,
    'RetrieveSummary' => 0,
    'Random' => 0,
    'GetHtml' => 0,
    'ContentType' => 'AllTypes',
    )
  );
}
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
  echo $exception;
}
```

but I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  I'm stepping through this is a debugger, and I can see that $client is an object.  Is there something else I'm doing wrong that would cause this error?  Also, am I structuring my SOAP call correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong, the error is in the service so one of two things can be the case:

1. One of your parameters is wrong and makes the service resolve to a null object (path could be a candidate) and the server doesn't validate this and try to so operations on the object
2. There is a general malfunction in the service you are calling